# How do I resolve this go_router error: too many redirects?

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, mobile

When I run the app, I get an error in the emulator saying too many redirects. I am using go_router in flutter
this is the redirect part of my code:
`redirect: (state) {

```
  final loggedIn = appStateManager.isLoggedIn;

  final loggingIn = state.subloc == '/login';

  if (!loggedIn) return loggingIn ? null : '/login';

  final isOnboardingComplete =
      appStateManager.isOnboardingComplete;

  final onboarding = state.subloc == '/onboarding';

  if (!isOnboardingComplete) {
    return onboarding ? null : '/onboarding';
  }

  if (loggingIn || onboarding) return '/${FooderlichTab.explore}';

  return null;
},`
```

I need help with it.